# Reference(book or article) for an explicit formula of Legendre polynomials

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, reference-request, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

The following explicit formula is stated for Legendre polynomials on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Rodrigues%27_formula_and_other_explicit_formulas).

\begin{equation}
   P_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}{n+k \choose k} \left(\dfrac{x-1}{2}\right)^2
\end{equation}

Do you know any proof or reference for this formula?

Comment: Apply Gram-Schmidt to the linearly independent polynomials $\{1,x,\ldots,x^n\}$ using the standard inner product on $L^2$. http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/Spring09/legendre.pdf

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Thank you for your comment. I know how to derivative Legendre polynomials. But, I cannot obtain the above explicit formula.

Comment: There are several proofs of Legendre polynomial  closed forms at this [link](https://pnp.mathematik.uni-stuttgart.de/iadm/Riedel/egorychev.html#legendrepoly).

Comment: @Marko Riedel Thank you for your reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Wikipedia's page there is the following Bonnet's recursion formula:
$$(n+1)P_{n+1}(x)=(2n+1)xP_n(x)-nP_{n-1}(x)$$
Now, let $a_{n,k}=\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}$. Then, esentially, we must show that $P_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_{n,k}\left(\frac{x-1}{2}\right)^k$ satisfies this recursive equation. Then, we have
$$(n+1)\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}a_{n+1,k}\left(\frac{x-1}{2}\right)^k=(2n+1)x\sum_{k=0}^na_{n,k}\left(\frac{x-1}{2}\right)^k-n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{n-1,k}\left(\frac{x-1}{2}\right)^k.$$
Lets do this trick: $x=2\left(\frac{x-1}{2}\right)+1$. Then we, essentially. must show that
$$(n+1)a_{n+1,k}=2(2n+1)a_{n,k-1}+(2n+1)a_{n,k}-na_{n-1,k}$$
And after some simplifications, by multiplying from numerators or denominators, I got
$$(n+1)(n+k+1)(n+k)=2(2n+1)k^2+(2n+1)(n-k+1)(n+k)-n(n-k+1)(n-k)$$
and these are equal.

Comment: Dear @Bob Dobbs , thank you for your valuable answer.